# three.js camera rotating by touch events and deviceorientation event

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to build a webapp that let users watch 360 panorama images with three.js, but some of the code isn't working as expected. The problem involves rotating the camera.

I'm able to rotate the camera by listening to either touch events or deviceorientation events but I can't manage to make both work simultaneously.

Currently, the camera rotates by touch gesture, but it snaps back immediately after detecting a device orientation event.

I want the camera to rotate with touch gestures and then rotate with device orientation starting from the rotation it was previously set by touch.

I think I should improve `deviceorientation` event handler or `setQuaternion` method below in **add-gestures.js** but I don't know how.

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pages/vr/style.css') ?>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="vr-canvas"></canvas>

    <script src="/js/lib/threejs/r104/build/three.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/pages/vr/init-vr.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/pages/vr/add-gestures.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/pages/vr/add-sphere.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**init-vr.js**

```js
window.VRApp = window.VRApp || {};

const canvas = document.querySelector("#vr-canvas");

const renderer = (() => {
  const webGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });

  webGLRenderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

  return webGLRenderer;
})();

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = (() => {
  const perspectiveCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.01, 100);

  perspectiveCamera.rotation.order = "ZYX";

  return perspectiveCamera;
})();

const animate = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();

window.VRApp.renderer = renderer;
window.VRApp.scene = scene;
window.VRApp.camera = camera;
```

**add-gestures.js**

```js
window.VRApp = window.VRApp || {};

const State = {
  Neutral: 0x0000,
  RotateCamera: 0x0001,
};

let state = State.Neutral;

let windowOrientation = window.orientation || 0;
let cameraRotationCache = window.VRApp.camera.rotation.clone();

let mousePositionCache = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  minYDiff: 0,
  maxYDiff: 0,
};

const setState = (newState) => {
  if (State.hasOwnProperty(newState)) {
    state = State[newState];
  }
};

const checkState = (targetState) => {
  if (State.hasOwnProperty(targetState)) {
    return state === State[targetState];
  }

  return false;
};

const setQuaternion = (() => {
  const zee = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
  const euler = new THREE.Euler();
  const q0 = new THREE.Quaternion();
  const q1 = new THREE.Quaternion(-1 * Math.sqrt(0.5), 0, 0, Math.sqrt(0.5));

  return (alpha, beta, gamma, orientation) => {
    euler.set(beta, alpha, -1 * gamma, "YXZ");

    window.VRApp.camera.quaternion.setFromEuler(euler);
    window.VRApp.camera.quaternion.multiply(q1);
    window.VRApp.camera.quaternion.multiply(q0.setFromAxisAngle(zee, -1 * orientation));
  };
})();

const onMouseDownHandler = (clientX, clientY) => {
  setState("RotateCamera");

  cameraRotationCache = window.VRApp.camera.rotation.clone();

  mousePositionCache.x = clientX;
  mousePositionCache.y = clientY;
  mousePositionCache.minYDiff = -90 - (cameraRotationCache.x * (180 / Math.PI)) - (clientY * (Math.PI / 180));
  mousePositionCache.maxYDiff = 90 - (cameraRotationCache.x * (180 / Math.PI)) - (clientY * (Math.PI / 180));
};


const onMouseMoveHandler = (clientX, clientY) => {
  if (checkState("RotateCamera")) {
    window.VRApp.camera.rotation.order = "ZYX";

    let xDiff = clientX - mousePositionCache.x;
    let yDiff = clientY - mousePositionCache.y;

    if (yDiff < mousePositionCache.minYDiff) {
      yDiff = mousePositionCache.minYDiff;

      mousePositionCache.y = clientY - mousePositionCache.minYDiff;
    }

    if (yDiff > mousePositionCache.maxYDiff) {
      yDiff = mousePositionCache.maxYDiff;

      mousePositionCache.y = clientY - mousePositionCache.maxYDiff;
    }

    let newAngleX = cameraRotationCache.x + (yDiff * (Math.PI / 180));
    let newAngleY = cameraRotationCache.y + (xDiff * (Math.PI / 180));

    window.VRApp.camera.rotation.x = newAngleX;
    window.VRApp.camera.rotation.y = newAngleY;
  }
};

const onMouseUpHandler = () => {
  setState("Neutral");

  cameraRotationCache = window.VRApp.camera.rotation.clone();

  mousePositionCache.x = 0;
  mousePositionCache.y = 0;
  mousePositionCache.minYDiff = 0;
  mousePositionCache.maxYDiff = 0;
};

if ("onresize" in window) {
  window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;

    window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.width = width;
    window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.height = height;

    window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.style.height = height + "px";

    window.VRApp.renderer.setSize(width, height);

    window.VRApp.camera.aspect = width / height;
    window.VRApp.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });
}

if ("onload" in window) {
  window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;

    window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.width = width;
    window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.height = height;

    window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.style.height = height + "px";

    window.VRApp.renderer.setSize(width, height);

    window.VRApp.camera.aspect = width / height;
    window.VRApp.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });
}

if ("onmousedown" in window.VRApp.renderer.domElement) {
  window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
    onMouseDownHandler(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  });
}

if ("onmousemove" in window.VRApp.renderer.domElement) {
  window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    onMouseMoveHandler(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  });
}

if ("onmouseup" in window.VRApp.renderer.domElement) {
  window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
    onMouseUpHandler();
  });
}

if ("onmouseleave" in window.VRApp.renderer.domElement) {
  window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
    onMouseUpHandler();
  });
}

if ("ontouchstart" in window.VRApp.renderer.domElement) {
  window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.addEventListener("touchstart", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.touches.length === 1) {
      const touch = event.touches[0];

      onMouseDownHandler(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
    }
  });
}

if ("ontouchmove" in window.VRApp.renderer.domElement) {
  window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.addEventListener("touchmove", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.touches.length === 1) {
      const touch = event.touches[0];

      onMouseMoveHandler(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
    }
  });
}

if ("ontouchend" in window.VRApp.renderer.domElement) {
  window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.addEventListener("touchend", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    onMouseUpHandler();
  });
}

if ("ontouchcancel" in window.VRApp.renderer.domElement) {
  window.VRApp.renderer.domElement.addEventListener("touchcancel", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    onMouseUpHandler();
  });
}

if ("onorientationchange" in window) {
  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", (event) => {
    windowOrientation = window.orientation || 0;
  });
}

if ("ondeviceorientation" in window) {
  window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", (event) => {
    if (checkState("Neutral")) {
      let alpha = event.alpha * (Math.PI / 180);
      let beta = event.beta * (Math.PI / 180);
      let gamma = event.gamma * (Math.PI / 180);
      let orientation = windowOrientation * (Math.PI / 180);

      setQuaternion(alpha, beta, gamma, orientation);
    }
  });
}
```

**add-sphere.js**

```js
window.VRApp = window.VRApp || {};

const sphere = (() => {
  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 64, 64);

  geometry.scale(1, 1, -1);
  geometry.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);

  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  });

  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  return mesh;
})();

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture = textureLoader.load("/img/pages/vr/sample-360.jpg");

sphere.material.map = texture;

window.VRApp.scene.add(sphere);
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463600/object-rotation-using-the-device-orientation-controls-in-three-js
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283320/three-js-rotate-camera-with-both-touch-and-device-orientation